# java.util.Iterator<String> to InputStream of gzipped data

Tags: java, streaming, java-io

My client has an API which takes an InputStream as parameter and my data comes   in a java.util.Iterator, so basically I need to transfer the data from one Iterator into an InputStream. Even more, I want to tranfer it in a GZIP format so basically I need to produce an InputStream with the the contents of Iterator gzipped.

Since I want to be as fast and memory efficient as possible, I would appreciate a "streaming" solution (I already know that I can write the data in a file with a GZIPOutputStream and then read it with an FileInputStream)

Comment: Why would you want to produce a `GZIPInputStream`, i.e. a stream of uncompressed data from a compressed source, when your source is already uncompressed?

Comment: @Andreas, I guess you are right, I still need an InputStream but with Gzip compressed data..so actually I need a way to produce Gzip on the fly from my Iterator<String>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your own logic using [`Deflater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) to compress the data, and you need to implement an [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), where you should implement at least the [`read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--), [`read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-int-int-), and [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#close--) methods.

Here is my take, in pseudo-code, on how to implement `read`:

```
public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) {
    if deflater finished:
        return -1
    if deflater needs input:
        get next string from iterator
        deflater.setInput(s.getBytes("UTF-8"))
        if iterator at end:
            deflater.finish()
    deflate into b using off and len
}
```

That is of course simplified. You'll need to correctly initialize the deflater, handle empty iterator, separate the strings with line breaks, etc.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I will have a look into Deflator. Hopefully the Deflator does not need all data at once ...

Comment: @humbletrader It does not, that's why the pseudo-code keeps calling `setInput()` for each string in the iterator. When you make the last call, you also call `finish()` to tell the deflater it's the last part.